# Can't close camera using useRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I want to use user's camera and close it using react function component. But it doesn't work. But I think it's correct to use `stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());`

```js
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const [cameraOpen, setCameraOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const video = videoRef.current;
    const constraints: MediaStreamConstraints = { audio: false, video: true };
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then((stream) => {
        if (video) {
          video.srcObject = stream;
          video.play();
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
    return () => {
      const stream = videoRef.current?.srcObject as MediaStream;
      if (stream) {
        stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: You never assign anything to `videoRef.current`

Comment: @Konrad But when I use videoRef to display the picture, it is ok